# How to fold a paper into a flat model and when we pull on a side it goes 3D

Tags: origami

I saw a pretty interesting origami in this video :

https://youtu.be/0Z-eWYhtEhY?t=3092

but I can't figure out how to fold it. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: I believed that my youtube link contains the time

Comment: I think it is Momotani's Brick Wall, and there seems to be a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUOVVSUDgQ4